# Nameserver Issues

Tags: domains, web-hosting, nameserver, cloud-hosting

I have a dedicated server on which I host my websites via cpanel. The domain registrar is a uk hosting company. Now, I want to move to a cloud VMware server with another company. My server and cpanel has been set up. I have a problem with moving my nameservers.

How do I transfer the nameservers on my old dedicated server to my new cloud server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like larrylampco above, I am assuming you have sites hosted on a dedicated server with company A and you would like to switch your sites to a server with company B. I am also assuming you are currently hosting your own DNS on your own domain on your dedicated server with Company A (such as ns1.yourdomain.com and ns2.yourdomain.com) and not using provided nameservers (such as ns1.webhostname.com and ns2.webhostname.com) which are mostly used when using shared or reseller hosting.

If both servers are using cPanel then you can create a DNS cluster setting the sync option to "Synchronize Changes". This should sync all host files from server A to server B. At this point server B would have all the information on it to start serving DNS queries (even though we haven't started sending any yet).

Next would be to edit the host file of the domain you use for nameservers to account for the change of nameserver IP. So log back into WHM on server B and go to "Home »
DNS Functions » Edit DNS Zone" and select the host file for the domain you use for nameservers. Then change the A records for your NS1 and NS2 and point them to server B.

At this point you will have to log into your domain registrar and register the nameservers with the same IPs as used in the paragraph above, this is to ensure proper GLUE. This is because your nameservers are on the same domain you will be using for content. I'm terrible at explaining and wiki says best ///

> For example, if the authoritative name server for example.org is
>   ns1.example.org, a computer trying to resolve www.example.org first
>   resolves ns1.example.org. Since ns1 is contained in example.org, this
>   requires resolving example.org first, which presents a circular
>   dependency. To break the dependency, the name server for the top level
>   domain org includes glue along with the delegation for example.org.
>   The glue records are address records that provide IP addresses for
>   ns1.example.org. The resolver uses one or more of these IP addresses
>   to query one of the domain's authoritative servers, which allows it to
>   complete the DNS query.

Now you can disable the DNS cluster as you have just moved your DNS from Server A to Server B all while the actual nameservers haven't changed :)

When finished, I suggest using intodns.com to check all your results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have sites hosted on a dedicated server with company A and you would like to switch your sites to a server with company B. In order to do this, you need to change the nameservers with your current registrar to point from company A to company B. I am assuming you have setup the sites on Company B's server so that when DNS propagation is complete, you can see your sites.

Comment: Ok. so how do I get company B's nameserver?

Comment: @Bobo I can't tell you exactly since all hosting providers are different but most hosting providers will provide this information in their control panel or user documents. If you are unsure, I would just email them and ask what the nameservers need to be. This is a common question that they should be used to answering.

Comment: The server was set up today by company B, and in cpanel, the nameservers are listed as ns1.yourhostname.domain, ns2.yourhostname.domain.

Comment: @Bobo are you using WHM (Web Host Manager) and mistaking it for cpanel? Normally, the "yourhostname" is the primary domain that you used to setup your account or the username of your account.

Comment: Sorry I meant WHM. My server hostname is server.rv.com

Comment: @Bobo If you go to Home »Server Configuration »Basic cPanel & WHM Setup you should see your nameservers listed there. These should be the nameservers that you use whenever you setup a new domain on this server.

Comment: That is the same location I found ns1.your host name.domain and the ns2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9973/discussion-between-larrylampco-and-bobo)